# How do I make the Wordpress author page private for logged in users only?

Tags: wordpress

I look after a Wordpress site for a member only organisation. The site consists of public pages and other pages that can only be viewed if you are logged in.

One of the pieces they want to make private, for logged in users only, is the author/biographical info that they can complete in their user profile (e.g. http:///author//). At the moment the biographical info can be viewed openly online without being logged in. But they want to keep this info for logged in members only.

PS: I've disallowed this directory in the robot.txt file but the author pages are still technically open.

Any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: is_user_logged_in() function  will help you https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: Ah.. great thank you. I can apply that.